# Can I get a list of users who have authorized my Twitter app?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to get a list of users who have authorized my Twitter application. I've tried checking the API docs, but there seems to be no twitter application specific APIs that I can find. I'm trying to avoid having to store these twitter user names myself, since the user list would be the exact same as Twitter's authorized user list and even handle deauthorized users for me.

Comment: you will run into this problem sooner or later http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/306516/best-way-to-intersect-a-big-set-with-another-big-set-from-a-database?noredirect=1#comment642732_306516

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to obtain this information from the Twitter API. If you're interested in keeping track of the users who are using your application, you'll need to track it yourself.

Comment: This is a bummer.  This would be very useful.